# grep results of wildcard show up as blank lines with files ending in CRLF

Tags: grep

To show only the term I wish to find (for example, `temperature`) and the immediately surrounding text, I am calling `grep ".\{0,5\}temperature.\{0,5\}" *`

This command works fine when the files have Unix end-of-lines. However, when searching files created in Windows (that end in CRLF), instead of grep showing the right result, the entire line appears blank whenever CRLF is within the 5-character range.

I have tried the `-U` (binary) flag to no avail.

Here is the file I am using to test. I have a version saved with CRLF endings (test_dos.txt), and another with just LF (test_unix.txt):

```
the body temperature is the variable
temperature12345678
temperature1234567
temperature123456
temperature12345
temperature1234
temperature123
temperature12
temperature1
temperature

woie temperature!! tempe oaj
```

The result of calling `grep -o ".\{0,5\}temperature.\{0,5\}" *` is:

```
test_dos.txt:body temperature is t
test_dos.txt:temperature12345
test_dos.txt:temperature12345
test_dos.txt:temperature12345
test_dos.txt:temperature12345





test_dos.txt:woie temperature!! te
test_unix.txt:body temperature is t
test_unix.txt:temperature12345
test_unix.txt:temperature12345
test_unix.txt:temperature12345
test_unix.txt:temperature12345
test_unix.txt:temperature1234
test_unix.txt:temperature123
test_unix.txt:temperature12
test_unix.txt:temperature1
test_unix.txt:temperature
test_unix.txt:woie temperature!! te
```

What can I do so that grep shows the correct results with the Windows/DOS file?

Comment: Which version of `grep` is this? I don't have time to dig into this, but if this is GNU grep, it seems the `--color` option somehow interferes with its handling of CR in DOS-formatted files. I was not able to reproduce it when also using `-o`, however. Try running it as `/bin/grep` or `\grep` to ensure you aren't executing an alias that specifies additional options.

Comment: @JamesSneeringer yes, that's it!! I would never have guessed. If you post it as an answer i will accept it. It's GNU grep 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you don't have an alias for `grep` that specifies additional options. Experimentally, it seems the `--color` option of GNU `grep` somehow interferes with its handling of CR in DOS-formatted files, which results in the output described in some cases. You can bypass an alias definition by prefixing the command with a `\` (e.g., `\grep`), or by specifying the full path to the executable (e.g., `/bin/grep`).